# Debugging Issue with Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code: 'ipykernel setup required' and Print Statement Failures

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, miniconda

I'm experiencing an issue when trying to debug a Jupyter notebook in Visual Studio Code. I have a cell with multiple interactive widgets, using ipywidgets. When I start debugging, I receive the following errors and warnings:

```
[error] Failed to handle iopub message as a result of some comm message {
...
} Error: Cannot call start again
```

```
[warn] Cell completed with errors undefined
```

I can run all the cells in the notebook fine, and the print statements work as expected for a few executions, or until I try to debug. After I try to debug, I get a dialog box saying 'ipykernel setup required for this feature', the print statements no longer show up, and commands like `conda info` also produce no output.

I've tried the following steps:

- Updating, uninstalling, and reinstalling ipykernel, Jupyter, Miniconda3 and the Python extension
- Updating, uninstalling, and reinstalling VS Code
- Reloading the VS Code window
- Complete uninstallation and reinstallation of VS Code and Python, including deletion of related folders in my home directory, appdata, and program files.

None of these steps have resolved the issue. Many times, restarting the kernel or reloading the window will fix it temporarily, but now debugging will not work regardless.
I think the problem is related to how my path variables are configured, and they are not allowing Miniconda3 to work with VS Code and Jupyter.

- Miniconda3 installation path: `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\miniconda3`
- Python interpreter path in VS Code: `C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder\.conda\python.exe`
- PATH environment variable:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\miniconda3;
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Library\usr\bin;
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Library\bin;
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Scripts;
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\miniconda3\bin;
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\miniconda3\condabin;
```

- Conda environments:

```
base                  *  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\miniconda3
                         C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder\.conda
                         c:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder\.conda
```

I'm using the following versions:

```
Operating System: Windows 11 Enterprise Version 21H2
VS Code: 1.84.2
Python extension: v2023.20.0
Python: 3.10.12
IPython: 8.15.0
ipykernel: 6.25.0
ipywidgets: 8.1.1
jupyter_client: 8.6.0
jupyter_core: 5.5.0
jupyter_server: 2.10.0
jupyterlab: 4.0.8
nbclient: 0.8.0
nbconvert: 7.10.0
nbformat: 5.9.2
notebook: 7.0.6
qtconsole: not installed
traitlets: 5.7.1
Managed by Minconda3
```

This is the output of `conda list`

```
# packages in environment at c:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder\.conda:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
adjusttext                0.7.3.1                    py_1    conda-forge
asttokens                 2.0.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
boltons                   23.0.0          py310haa95532_0
boost-cpp                 1.82.0               h59b6b97_2
bottleneck                1.3.5           py310h9128911_0
brotli                    1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
brotli-python             1.0.9           py310hd77b12b_7
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2023.08.22           haa95532_0
cairo                     1.16.0               haedb8bc_5
cantera                   3.0.0           py310h3b7b6ab_2    conda-forge
certifi                   2023.7.22       py310haa95532_0
cffi                      1.15.1          py310h2bbff1b_3
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
colorama                  0.4.6           py310haa95532_0
comm                      0.1.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
comtypes                  1.1.14          py310haa95532_0
conda                     23.9.0          py310haa95532_0
conda-package-handling    2.2.0           py310haa95532_0
conda-package-streaming   0.9.0           py310haa95532_0
contourpy                 1.0.5           py310h59b6b97_0
cryptography              41.0.3          py310h89fc84f_0
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
debugpy                   1.6.7           py310hd77b12b_0
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
eigen                     3.3.7                h59b6b97_1
entrypoints               0.4             py310haa95532_0
et_xmlfile                1.1.0           py310haa95532_0
exceptiongroup            1.0.4           py310haa95532_0
executing                 0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
expat                     2.5.0                hd77b12b_0
fmt                       10.1.1               h181d51b_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono 2.37                 hd3eb1b0_0
font-ttf-inconsolata      2.001                hcb22688_0
font-ttf-source-code-pro  2.030                hd3eb1b0_0
font-ttf-ubuntu           0.83                 h8b1ccd4_0
fontconfig                2.14.1               h9c4af85_2
fonts-anaconda            1                    h8fa9717_0
fonts-conda-ecosystem     1                    hd3eb1b0_0
fonttools                 4.25.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
freetype                  2.12.1               ha860e81_0
fribidi                   1.0.10               h62dcd97_0
getopt-win32              0.1                  h2bbff1b_0
giflib                    5.2.1                h8cc25b3_3
glib                      2.69.1               h5dc1a3c_2
graphite2                 1.3.14               hd77b12b_1
graphviz                  2.50.0               h7eca76f_1
gst-plugins-base          1.18.5               h9e645db_0
gstreamer                 1.18.5               hd78058f_0
gts                       0.7.6                h63ab5a1_3
harfbuzz                  4.3.0                hb646838_1
hdf5                      1.14.2          nompi_h73e8ff5_100    conda-forge
icc_rt                    2022.1.0             h6049295_2
icu                       58.2                 ha925a31_3
idna                      3.4             py310haa95532_0
intel-openmp              2023.1.0         h59b6b97_46320
ipykernel                 6.25.0          py310h9909e9c_0
ipython                   8.15.0          py310haa95532_0
ipywidgets                8.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.18.1          py310haa95532_1
jpeg                      9e                   h2bbff1b_1
jsonpatch                 1.32               pyhd3eb1b0_0
jsonpointer               2.1                pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_client            8.6.0           py310haa95532_0
jupyter_core              5.5.0           py310haa95532_0
jupyterlab_widgets        3.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.4.4           py310hd77b12b_0
krb5                      1.21.2               heb0366b_0    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.12                 h83e58a3_0
lerc                      3.0                  hd77b12b_0
libaec                    1.1.2                h63175ca_1    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0              19_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libboost                  1.82.0               h3399ecb_2
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
libcantera                3.0.0                h4d0b157_2    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0              19_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libclang                  12.0.0          default_h627e005_2
libcurl                   8.4.0                hd5e4a3a_0    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.17                 h2bbff1b_1
libffi                    3.4.4                hd77b12b_0
libgd                     2.3.3                hd77b12b_3
libiconv                  1.16                 h2bbff1b_2
liblapack                 3.9.0              19_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libogg                    1.3.5                h2bbff1b_1
libopencv                 4.6.0                haa95532_5
libpng                    1.6.39               h8cc25b3_0
libprotobuf               3.20.3               h23ce68f_0
libsodium                 1.0.18               h62dcd97_0
libsqlite                 3.44.0               hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.11.0               h7dfc565_0    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.5.1                hd77b12b_0
libvorbis                 1.3.7                he774522_0
libwebp                   1.2.4                hbc33d0d_1
libwebp-base              1.2.4                h2bbff1b_1
libxml2                   2.10.4               h0ad7f3c_1
libxslt                   1.1.37               h2bbff1b_1
libzlib                   1.2.13               hcfcfb64_5    conda-forge
lxml                      4.9.3           py310h09808a7_0
lz4-c                     1.9.4                h2bbff1b_0
matplotlib                3.8.0           py310haa95532_0
matplotlib-base           3.8.0           py310h4ed8f06_0
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6           py310haa95532_0
menuinst                  1.4.19          py310h59b6b97_0
mkl                       2023.2.0         h6a75c08_50496    conda-forge
mkl-service               2.4.0           py310h2bbff1b_1
mkl_fft                   1.3.8           py310h2bbff1b_0
mkl_random                1.2.4           py310h59b6b97_0
munkres                   1.1.4                      py_0
nest-asyncio              1.5.6           py310haa95532_0
numexpr                   2.8.7           py310h2cd9be0_0
numpy                     1.26.0          py310h055cbcc_0
numpy-base                1.26.0          py310h65a83cf_0
opencv                    4.6.0           py310ha7641e4_2
openjpeg                  2.4.0                h4fc8c34_0
openpyxl                  3.0.10          py310h2bbff1b_0
openssl                   3.1.4                hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
packaging                 23.1            py310haa95532_0
pandas                    2.1.1           py310h4ed8f06_0
pango                     1.50.7               h78c2152_0
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pcre                      8.45                 hd77b12b_0
pdf2image                 1.16.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pillow                    9.4.0           py310hd77b12b_0
pip                       23.3            py310haa95532_0
pixman                    0.40.0               h2bbff1b_1
pkgutil-resolve-name      1.3.10             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
platformdirs              3.10.0          py310haa95532_0
plotly                    5.17.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pluggy                    1.0.0           py310haa95532_1
ply                       3.11            py310haa95532_0
poppler                   22.12.0              h0bf3bde_3
poppler-data              0.4.11               haa95532_1
prompt-toolkit            3.0.36          py310haa95532_0
psutil                    5.9.0           py310h2bbff1b_0
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
py-opencv                 4.6.0                haa95532_5
pycosat                   0.6.6           py310h2bbff1b_0
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pygments                  2.15.1          py310haa95532_1
pyopenssl                 23.2.0          py310haa95532_0
pyparsing                 3.0.9           py310haa95532_0
pyqt                      5.15.10         py310hd77b12b_0
pyqt5-sip                 12.13.0         py310h2bbff1b_0
pysocks                   1.7.1           py310haa95532_0
pytesseract               0.3.13             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python                    3.10.12         h4de0772_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-graphviz           0.20.1          py310haa95532_0
python-tzdata             2023.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0
python_abi                3.10                    4_cp310    conda-forge
pytz                      2023.3.post1    py310haa95532_0
pywin32                   305             py310h2bbff1b_0
pywinauto                 0.6.8           py310h5588dad_6    conda-forge
pyzmq                     25.1.1          py310hcd737a0_1    conda-forge
qt-main                   5.15.2               he8e5bd7_7
qt-webengine              5.15.9               h5bd16bc_7
qtwebkit                  5.212                h2bbfb41_5
requests                  2.31.0          py310haa95532_0
ruamel.yaml               0.17.21         py310h2bbff1b_0
ruamel.yaml.clib          0.2.6           py310h2bbff1b_1
ruamel_yaml               0.17.21         py310h2bbff1b_0
scipy                     1.11.3          py310h309d312_0
setuptools                68.0.0          py310haa95532_0
sip                       6.7.12          py310hd77b12b_0
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
sqlite                    3.41.2               h2bbff1b_0
stack_data                0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sundials                  6.6.2                h2434545_1    conda-forge
tbb                       2021.8.0             h59b6b97_0
tenacity                  8.2.2           py310haa95532_0
tk                        8.6.12               h2bbff1b_0
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
tomli                     2.0.1           py310haa95532_0
tornado                   6.3.3           py310h2bbff1b_0
tqdm                      4.65.0          py310h9909e9c_0
traitlets                 5.7.1           py310haa95532_0
truststore                0.8.0           py310haa95532_0
tzdata                    2023c                h04d1e81_0
ucrt                      10.0.20348.0         haa95532_0
urllib3                   1.26.18         py310haa95532_0
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vc14_runtime              14.36.32532         hdcecf7f_17    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.36.32532         h05e6639_17    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
wheel                     0.41.2          py310haa95532_0
widgetsnbextension        4.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
win_inet_pton             1.1.0           py310haa95532_0
xz                        5.4.2                h8cc25b3_0
yaml-cpp                  0.8.0                hd77b12b_0
zeromq                    4.3.4                hd77b12b_0
zlib                      1.2.13               hcfcfb64_5    conda-forge
zstandard                 0.19.0          py310h2bbff1b_0
zstd                      1.5.5                hd43e919_0
```

Comment: Could you please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which may help us reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> ipykernel setup required for this feature

This means that the ipykernel package wasn't installed in the current jupyter kernel.

You can click the top right button to change the current jupyter kernel.

[image]

Another way is to install the ipykernel package in your current environment.

Comment: I have ipykernel installed. I've uninstalled, reinstalled, and updated it several times. I have it listed in the output of `conda list`. I also can use features of ipykernel before I try debugging, but after debugging, ipykernel stops working.